# Soft Brush for Paint App?

Tags: objective-c, ios, opengl-es, core-graphics, quartz-graphics

Like in Photoshop and many other painting/photo editing program that it lets you set the hardness of the brush. 
Is it possible to do this with core graphics? Or I have to use OpenGL

PS. If I have to use OpenGL give me some codes and more details.

Comment: try using a shadow with shadow-color equals fill/stroke-color with offset 0,0

Comment: @JonathanCichon Will using shadow still work if I set it's blending mode to clear?

Comment: Don't sure, you have to try. But i think the blending mode should apply after the shadow.

Comment: maybe you have to import `<QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>` and link to the quartz core framework. Not sure why you get the problem.

Comment: Ok it's working now. I forgot to read that it's CGSize but thanks anyway.

Comment: @JonathanCichon Is there a way to set a higher opacity for the shadow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try `CGContextSetShadowWithColor`. The Shadow opacity depends on the shadow-color and the opacity of the drawn object. I believe applying a shadow to a full-tranzparent object is not possible without some masking.

... damn i wanted to add a new comment...

Comment: Performance will not be great with this method, better to just stamp a masked image with the desired color.